# code comment finder

Tags: c

This all started when I wanted to make a simple program that takes in a c or c++ file and outputs all the comments found. After doing that I thought why not expand the program to other programming languages which was mostly easy except for rust as it allows nested c style comments. However after completing that and adding support for directories I managed to finish the program

`comments.c`

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include "argva.c"

HANDLE stdout = NULL;
HANDLE stderr = NULL;

__declspec(noreturn) static void error_messagea(size_t count, char const **messages)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        char const *message = messages[i];
        WriteFile(stderr, message, lstrlenA(message), NULL, NULL);
    }
    ExitProcess(GetLastError());
}

#define error_messagea(...) error_messagea(sizeof((char const*[]){__VA_ARGS__}) / sizeof(char const *), (char const*[]){__VA_ARGS__})
#define WriteFile(filepath, ...) if(!WriteFile(__VA_ARGS__)) { error_messagea("Error could not write to ", filepath); }

typedef enum comment_display
{
    NO_COMMENT_DISPLAY = 0x0,
    C_COMMENT_DISPLAY = 0x1,
    CC_COMMENT_DISPLAY = C_COMMENT_DISPLAY << 1,
    ASM_COMMENT_DISPLAY = CC_COMMENT_DISPLAY << 1,
    PYTHON_COMMENT_DISPLAY = ASM_COMMENT_DISPLAY << 1,
    RUST_COMMENT_DISPLAY = PYTHON_COMMENT_DISPLAY << 1,
    AUTO_COMMENT_DISPLAY = RUST_COMMENT_DISPLAY << 1,
    C_AND_CC_COMMENT_DISPLAY = C_COMMENT_DISPLAY | CC_COMMENT_DISPLAY,
    ALL_COMMENT_DISPLAY = C_COMMENT_DISPLAY | CC_COMMENT_DISPLAY | ASM_COMMENT_DISPLAY
} comment_display;

typedef struct comment_count
{
    /* c comment count */
    size_t c_comment_count;

    /* c++ comment count */
    size_t cc_comment_count;

    /* asm comment count */
    size_t asm_comment_count;

    /* python comment count */
    size_t python_comment_count;

    /* rust comment count */
    size_t rust_comment_count;
} comment_count;

static void output_number(size_t number)
{
    /* log10(2^64) is around 20 meaning this should be able to hold all numbers inputed */
    char digits[20] = { '0' };

    /* get the reversed digets of the number */
    int i = number == 0 ? 1 : 0; /* check if number is zero */
    for (; number != 0; ++i) {
        digits[i] = (number % 10) + '0';
        number /= 10;
    }

    /* reverse the reversed digets of the number */
    for (int j = 0; j < i - 1; ++j) {
        char temp_digit = digits[j];
        digits[j] = digits[i - 1 - j];
        digits[i - 1 - j] = temp_digit;
    }

    /* print the reversed number */
    WriteFile("stdout", stdout, digits, i, NULL, NULL);
}

static char const *is_continuing_backslash(char const *str)
{
    /* NOTE: the loop is needed because cotinuing backslashs can nested like \\\\\ */
    if (*str != '\\') return NULL;
    while (*str != '\0') {
        switch (*str) {
            case '\r':
                break;
            case '\n':
                return str + 1;
            case '\\':
                break;
            default:
                return NULL;
        }

        ++str;
    }

    return NULL;
}

static comment_display get_comment_mode(char const *str)
{
    char const *file_extension_pos = str;

    /* find location of the file extension in the string */
    {
        char const *temp_pos = NULL;
        while (*file_extension_pos != '\0') {
            if (*file_extension_pos == '.') {
                temp_pos = file_extension_pos;
            }
            ++file_extension_pos;
        }

        if (temp_pos == NULL) {
            return C_AND_CC_COMMENT_DISPLAY;
        }

        file_extension_pos = temp_pos;
    }

    /* file extensions of languages the use c/c++ style comments */
    static char const *const cc_file_extensions[] = {
        ".c",
        ".cpp",
        ".h",
        ".hpp",
        ".cc",
        ".hh",
        ".java",
        ".cs",
        ".cu",
        ".cuh",
        ".go"
        ".hxx",
        ".cxx",
        ".c++",
        ".h++",
    };

    /* check if the file extension is of a programming language that uses c/c++ style comments */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof(cc_file_extensions) / sizeof(char const *const)); ++i) {
        if (!lstrcmpiA(file_extension_pos, cc_file_extensions[i])) {
            return C_AND_CC_COMMENT_DISPLAY;
        }
    }

    if (!lstrcmpiA(file_extension_pos, ".asm") || !lstrcmpiA(file_extension_pos, ".s")) {
        return ASM_COMMENT_DISPLAY;
    }
    else if (!lstrcmpiA(file_extension_pos, ".py")) {
        return PYTHON_COMMENT_DISPLAY;
    }
    else if (!lstrcmpiA(file_extension_pos, ".rs")) {
        return RUST_COMMENT_DISPLAY;
    }
    else {
        return NO_COMMENT_DISPLAY;
    }
}

/* NOTE: this function requires a null terminated string */
static comment_count read_comments(char const *str, bool show_lines, comment_display comment_mode)
{
    /* check if can even display comments */
    if (comment_mode == NO_COMMENT_DISPLAY) {
        return (comment_count) { 0 };
    }

    comment_count result = { 0 };

    /* keep reading the next char until we reach a null terminator*/
    size_t bytes_since_newline = 1;
    size_t newline_count = 1;
    while (*str != '\0') {
        switch (*str) {
            /* handle "" and '' */
            case '"':
            case '\'': {
                /* we need to read the current char to know what type of quote we are using
                 * once we have already read the current char so we need to go to the next one
                 */
                char quote_type = *str++;

                /* check for python doc string */
                if (str[0] == quote_type && str[1] == quote_type) {
                    ++result.python_comment_count;
                    if ((comment_mode & PYTHON_COMMENT_DISPLAY)) {
                        /* add space before comment*/
                        do {
                            WriteFile("stdout", stdout, " ", 1, NULL, NULL);
                        } while (bytes_since_newline-- != 0);
                        ++bytes_since_newline;

                        str += 2;
                        while (*str != '\0') {
                            if (str[0] == quote_type && str[1] == quote_type && str[2] == quote_type) {
                                if (show_lines) {
                                    WriteFile("stdout", stdout, " ", 1, NULL, NULL);
                                    output_number(newline_count);
                                }

                                str += 2;
                                if (str[1] == '\n' || (str[1] == '\r' && str[2] == '\n')) {
                                    str += str[0] == '\n' ? 1 : 2;
                                    ++newline_count;
                                }
                                break;
                            }

                            WriteFile("stdout", stdout, str, 1, NULL, NULL);

                            ++str;

                            while (str[0] == '\n' || (str[0] == '\r' && str[1] == '\n')) {
                                if (show_lines) {
                                    /* output a number before the end of the line */
                                    WriteFile("stdout", stdout, " ", 1, NULL, NULL);
                                    output_number(newline_count);
                                }

                                WriteFile("stdout", stdout, "\r\n", 2, NULL, NULL);

                                str += str[0] == '\n' ? 1 : 2;
                                ++newline_count;
                            }
                        }

                        WriteFile("stdout", stdout, "\r\n", 2, NULL, NULL);
                    }
                    break;
                }


                while (*str != '\0' && *str != quote_type) {
                    /* just skip escape codes as the could containe " or ' */
                    if (*str == '\\') {
                        ++str;
                    }

                    if (*str == '\n') {
                        ++newline_count;
                    }
                    ++str;
                }

                break;
            }


            case '/':
                ++str;
                switch (*str) {
                    case '/':
                        ++result.cc_comment_count;
                        ++result.rust_comment_count;
                        if ((comment_mode & RUST_COMMENT_DISPLAY) || (comment_mode & CC_COMMENT_DISPLAY)) {

                            /* add space before comment*/
                            do {
                                WriteFile("stdout", stdout, " ", 1, NULL, NULL);
                            } while (bytes_since_newline-- != 0);
                            ++bytes_since_newline;

                            if (RUST_COMMENT_DISPLAY & comment_mode) {
                                if (str[1] == '!') {
                                    str += 2;
                                }
                                else if (str[1] == '/') {
                                    WriteFile("stdout", stdout, " ", 1, NULL, NULL);
                                    str += str[2] == '!' ? 3 : 2;
                                }
                                else {
                                    ++str;
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                ++str;
                            }
                            while (*str != '\0') {

                                /* stop when we reach the end of the line */
                                if (str[0] == '\n' || (str[0] == '\r' && str[1] == '\n')) {
                                    if (show_lines) {
                                        WriteFile("stdout", stdout, " ", 1, NULL, NULL);
                                        output_number(newline_count);
                                    }

                                    /* NOTE: when we increment the string before going to the end of loop
                                     * we must add to the string pointer by 1 less since we already
                                     * increment the string pointer at the end of the loop
                                     */
                                    str += str[0] == '\n' ? 0 : 1;
                                    ++newline_count;
                                    break;
                                }

                                /* if we detect \\ treat the next line as a comment */
                                char const *continuing_backslash_pos;
                                if ((continuing_backslash_pos = is_continuing_backslash(str)) != NULL) {

                                    /* since we are moving to a newline output the current line number */
                                    if (show_lines) {
                                        WriteFile("stdout", stdout, " ", 1, NULL, NULL);
                                        output_number(newline_count);
                                    }

                                    WriteFile("stdout", stdout, "\r\n", 2, NULL, NULL);

                                    str = continuing_backslash_pos;
                                    ++newline_count;
                                }

                                WriteFile("stdout", stdout, str, 1, NULL, NULL);

                                ++str;
                            }
                            WriteFile("stdout", stdout, "\r\n", 2, NULL, NULL);
                        }
                        break;

                    case '*':
                        if (comment_mode & RUST_COMMENT_DISPLAY) {
                            ++result.rust_comment_count;
                            /* add space before comment */
                            do {
                                WriteFile("stdout", stdout, " ", 1, NULL, NULL);
                            } while (bytes_since_newline-- != 0);
                            ++bytes_since_newline;

                            size_t bracket_count = 1;
                            str += str[1] == '!' ? 2 : 1;
                            while (*str != '\0' && bracket_count != 0) {
                                while (str[0] == '/' && str[1] == '*') {
                                    str += str[2] == '!' ? 4 : 3;
                                    ++bracket_count;
                                }

                                if (str[0] == '*' && str[1] == '/') {
                                    if (show_lines) {
                                        WriteFile("stdout", stdout, " ", 1, NULL, NULL);
                                        output_number(newline_count);
                                    }

                                    ++str;
                                    if (str[1] == '\n' || (str[1] == '\r' && str[2] == '\n')) {
                                        WriteFile("stdout", stdout, "\r\n", 2, NULL, NULL);

                                        str += str[0] == '\n' ? 1 : 2;
                                        ++newline_count;
                                    }
                                    --bracket_count;
                                }
                                else {
                                    if (str[0] == '\n' || (str[0] == '\r' && str[1] == '\n')) {
                                        if (show_lines) {
                                            /* output a number before the end of the line */
                                            WriteFile("stdout", stdout, " ", 1, NULL, NULL);
                                            output_number(newline_count);
                                        }

                                        WriteFile("stdout", stdout, "\r\n", 2, NULL, NULL);

                                        str += str[0] == '\n' ? 0 : 1;
                                        ++newline_count;
                                    }
                                    else {

                                        WriteFile("stdout", stdout, str, 1, NULL, NULL);
                                    }
                                }
                                ++str;
                            }

                            WriteFile("stdout", stdout, "\r\n", 2, NULL, NULL);
                        }
                        else if ((comment_mode & C_COMMENT_DISPLAY)) {
                            ++result.c_comment_count;
                            /* add space before comment */
                            do {
                                WriteFile("stdout", stdout, " ", 1, NULL, NULL);
                            } while (bytes_since_newline-- != 0);
                            ++bytes_since_newline;

                            while (*str != '\0') {
                                ++str;
                                if (str[0] == '*' && str[1] == '/') {
                                    if (show_lines) {
                                        WriteFile("stdout", stdout, " ", 1, NULL, NULL);
                                        output_number(newline_count);
                                    }

                                    ++str;
                                    if (str[1] == '\n' || (str[1] == '\r' && str[2] == '\n')) {
                                        str += str[0] == '\n' ? 1 : 2;
                                        ++newline_count;
                                    }
                                    break;
                                }

                                if (str[0] == '\n' || (str[0] == '\r' && str[1] == '\n')) {
                                    if (show_lines) {
                                        /* output a number before the end of the line */
                                        WriteFile("stdout", stdout, " ", 1, NULL, NULL);
                                        output_number(newline_count);
                                    }

                                    WriteFile("stdout", stdout, "\r\n", 2, NULL, NULL);

                                    str += str[0] == '\n' ? 0 : 1;
                                    ++newline_count;
                                }
                                else {
                                    WriteFile("stdout", stdout, str, 1, NULL, NULL);
                                }
                            }

                            WriteFile("stdout", stdout, "\r\n", 2, NULL, NULL);
                        }
                        break;
                }
                break;

            case '\n':
                bytes_since_newline = 0;
                ++newline_count;
                break;

            case ';':
                ++result.asm_comment_count;
                if ((comment_mode & ASM_COMMENT_DISPLAY)) {
                    /* add space before comment*/
                    do {
                        WriteFile("stdout", stdout, " ", 1, NULL, NULL);
                    } while (bytes_since_newline-- != 0);
                    ++bytes_since_newline;

                    ++str;
                    while (*str != '\0') {
                        if (str[0] == '\n' || (str[0] == '\r' && str[1] == '\n')) {
                            if (show_lines) {
                                WriteFile("stdout", stdout, " ", 1, NULL, NULL);
                                output_number(newline_count);
                            }

                            ++newline_count;
                            break;
                        }

                        WriteFile("stdout", stdout, str, 1, NULL, NULL);
                        ++str;
                    }

                    WriteFile("stdout", stdout, "\r\n", 2, NULL, NULL);
                }
                break;

            case '#':
                ++result.python_comment_count;
                if ((comment_mode & PYTHON_COMMENT_DISPLAY)) {
                    /* add space before comment*/
                    do {
                        WriteFile("stdout", stdout, " ", 1, NULL, NULL);
                    } while (bytes_since_newline-- != 0);
                    ++bytes_since_newline;

                    ++str;
                    while (*str != '\0') {
                        if (str[0] == '\n' || (str[0] == '\r' && str[1] == '\n')) {
                            if (show_lines) {
                                WriteFile("stdout", stdout, " ", 1, NULL, NULL);
                                output_number(newline_count);
                            }

                            str += str[0] == '\n' ? 0 : 1;
                            ++newline_count;
                            break;
                        }

                        WriteFile("stdout", stdout, str, 1, NULL, NULL);
                        ++str;
                    }

                    WriteFile("stdout", stdout, "\r\n", 2, NULL, NULL);
                }
                break;
        }
        ++str;
        bytes_since_newline += *str == '\t' ? 4 : 1; /* handle tabs */
    }

    return result;
}

static void read_file_comments(char const *filename, comment_display comment_mode, bool show_line_number, bool display_comment_count)
{
    if (comment_mode & AUTO_COMMENT_DISPLAY) {
        comment_mode = get_comment_mode(filename);
    }

    if (comment_mode & ~NO_COMMENT_DISPLAY) {
        WriteFile("stdout", stdout, filename, lstrlenA(filename), NULL, NULL);
        WriteFile("stdout", stdout, ": \r\n", 4, NULL, NULL);
    }
    else {
        return;
    }

    HANDLE file_handle = CreateFileA(filename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (file_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        error_messagea("Error: could not open file \"", filename, "\"");
    }

    /* get the file size */
    LARGE_INTEGER file_size;
    if (GetFileSizeEx(file_handle, &file_size) == FALSE) {
        error_messagea("Error: could not get the file size of \"", filename, "\\");
    }

    char *file_buffer = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, file_size.QuadPart + 1);
    file_buffer[file_size.QuadPart] = '\0'; /* add a null terminator */

    /* read the file into the file buffer */
    DWORD bytes_read = 0;
    if (ReadFile(file_handle, file_buffer, file_size.LowPart, &bytes_read, NULL) == FALSE || bytes_read != file_size.QuadPart) {
        error_messagea("Error: could not read ", filename);
    }

    /* process the file and read the comments */
    {
        comment_count count = read_comments(file_buffer, show_line_number, comment_mode);
        if (display_comment_count) {
            if (comment_mode & CC_COMMENT_DISPLAY) {
                WriteFile("stdout", stdout, "c++ style comments: ", 20, NULL, NULL);
                output_number(count.cc_comment_count);
                WriteFile("stdout", stdout, "\r\n", 2, NULL, NULL);
            }

            if (comment_mode & C_COMMENT_DISPLAY) {
                WriteFile("stdout", stdout, "c style comments: ", 18, NULL, NULL);
                output_number(count.c_comment_count);
                WriteFile("stdout", stdout, "\r\n", 2, NULL, NULL);
            }

            if (comment_mode & RUST_COMMENT_DISPLAY) {
                WriteFile("stdout", stdout, "rust style comments: ", 21, NULL, NULL);
                output_number(count.rust_comment_count);
                WriteFile("stdout", stdout, "\r\n", 2, NULL, NULL);
            }

            if (comment_mode & ASM_COMMENT_DISPLAY) {
                WriteFile("stdout", stdout, "asm style comments: ", 20, NULL, NULL);
                output_number(count.asm_comment_count);
                WriteFile("stdout", stdout, "\r\n", 2, NULL, NULL);
            }

            if (comment_mode & PYTHON_COMMENT_DISPLAY) {
                WriteFile("stdout", stdout, "python style comments: ", 23, NULL, NULL);
                output_number(count.python_comment_count);
                WriteFile("stdout", stdout, "\r\n", 2, NULL, NULL);
            }
        }
    }
}

typedef struct string
{
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
    char *data;
} string_t;

string_t make_string(char const *string)
{
    /* get the length of the string */
    size_t string_length = lstrlenA(string);

    string_t result = {
        .size = string_length,
        .capacity = string_length,
        .data = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, string_length + 1)
    };

    /* copy the string to result */
    for (char *first = result.data; first != result.data + result.size; ) {
        *first++ = *string++;
    }

    /* null terminator */
    result.data[result.size] = '\0';

    return result;
}

void string_cat(string_t *self, char const *string)
{
    if (string[0] == '\0') return;

    size_t string_length = lstrlenA(string);
    self->size += string_length;
    if (self->size > self->capacity) {
        self->capacity = self->size * 2;
        self->data = HeapReAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, self->data, (self->capacity + 1));
    }
    lstrcatA(self->data, string);
}

void string_free(string_t self)
{
    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, self.data);
}

void read_comments_in_directory(char const *input_path, comment_display comment_mode, bool show_line_number, bool display_comment_count)
{
    size_t stack_capacity = 1000;
    size_t stack_size = 1;
    string_t *stack_base = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, sizeof(string_t) * stack_capacity);
    string_t *stack_ptr = stack_base;

    *stack_ptr++ = make_string(input_path);
    while (stack_ptr != stack_base) {
        string_t path = stack_ptr[-1];
        string_t spec = make_string(path.data);
        string_cat(&spec, "\\*");
        --stack_ptr;
        --stack_size;

        WIN32_FIND_DATAA file_find_data;
        HANDLE find_handle = FindFirstFileA(spec.data, &file_find_data);
        if (find_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            string_free(spec);
            string_free(path);
            HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, stack_base);
            error_messagea("Error: FindFirstFileA failed");
        }

        do {
            if (lstrcmpA(file_find_data.cFileName, ".") != 0 &&
                lstrcmpA(file_find_data.cFileName, "..") != 0) {
                if (file_find_data.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {
                    ++stack_size;
                    if (stack_size > stack_capacity) {
                        stack_capacity = stack_size * 2;
                        stack_base = HeapReAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, stack_base, sizeof(string_t) * stack_capacity);
                        stack_ptr = stack_base + stack_size - 1;
                    }
                    *stack_ptr++ = make_string(path.data);
                    string_cat(stack_ptr - 1, "\\");
                    string_cat(stack_ptr - 1, file_find_data.cFileName);
                }
                else {
                    string_t file_name = make_string(path.data);
                    string_cat(&file_name, "\\");
                    string_cat(&file_name, file_find_data.cFileName);
                    read_file_comments(file_name.data, comment_mode, show_line_number, display_comment_count);
                    string_free(file_name);
                }
            }
        } while (FindNextFileA(find_handle, &file_find_data) != 0);

        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) {
            FindClose(find_handle);
            error_messagea("Error: FindNextFileA failed");
        }

        FindClose(find_handle);
        string_free(spec);
        string_free(path);
    }

    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, stack_base);
}

void read_comments_in_directory_non_recursive(char const *input_path, comment_display comment_mode, bool show_line_number, bool display_comment_count)
{
    string_t spec = make_string(input_path);
    string_cat(&spec, "\\*");

    WIN32_FIND_DATAA file_find_data;
    HANDLE find_handle = FindFirstFileA(spec.data, &file_find_data);
    if (find_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        string_free(spec);
        error_messagea("Error: FindFirstFileA failed");
    }

    string_t file_name = make_string(input_path);
    string_cat(&file_name, "\\");
    do {
        if (lstrcmpA(file_find_data.cFileName, ".") != 0 &&
            lstrcmpA(file_find_data.cFileName, "..") != 0) {
            if (file_find_data.dwFileAttributes & ~FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {
                string_cat(&file_name, file_find_data.cFileName);
                read_file_comments(file_name.data, comment_mode, show_line_number, display_comment_count);
                file_name.data[spec.size - 1] = '\0';
                file_name.size = spec.size - 1;
            }
        }
    } while (FindNextFileA(find_handle, &file_find_data) != 0);

    FindClose(find_handle);
    string_free(spec);
    string_free(file_name);
}

void __cdecl mainCRTStartup(void)
{
    static char const *help_message = "Usage: comments [--help] [-r false or true or --recursive= false or true] [-l or --line] [-c or --count] [-nl or --no_line] [-e [mode] or --enable=[mode]] [-m [mode] or --mode=[mode]] [-d [mode] or --disable=[mode]] [--display_comment_count or -dcc] [--hide_comment_count -hcc] [file1 ...]\n\
                                         Flags: \n\
                                        --help: displays this message \n\
                                        -r or --recursive=: using this with true enables recursive directory searching and using with false disables recursive directory search\n\
                                        -l or --line(disabled by default): makes it so the program shows the line number of each comment\n\
                                        -nl or --no_line: has the oppsite effect of -l\n\
                                        -e [mode] or --enable=[mode]: enables the comment mode to [mode] for example -e asm enables asm comments\n\
                                        -m [mode] or --mode=[mode]: sets the comment mode  to [mode] for example -m asm only allows only asm comments\n\
                                        -d [mode] or --disable=[mode]: disables the comment mode to [mode] for example -d asm disables asm comments\n\
                                        [mode](the default mode auto): the different modes are \n\
                                        c++ style comments //(cc, cxx, cpp), \n\
                                        c style comments /**/ (c), \n\
                                        python style comments (py), \n\
                                        asm style comments ;(asm), \n\
                                        c and c++ style comments /**/ //(c|c++), \n\
                                        rust style comments which enables rust style comments /*/* comments can be nested */*/ // /// //!(rs), \n\
                                        auto which detects the comment style based on file extension(auto), \n\
                                        and all which enables all the available comment styles(all) \n\
                                        -dcc or --display_comment_count(enabled by defualt): displays the number of comments found \n\
                                        -hcc or --hides_comment_count: hides the number of comments found \n\
                                        ";
    stdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    stderr = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);

    /* get command line args */
    int argc;
    char **argv = CommandLineToArgvA(GetCommandLineA(), &argc) + 1;
    --argc;

    bool show_lines = false;
    bool recursive_directory_search = false;
    bool display_comment_count = true;
    comment_display comment_mode = AUTO_COMMENT_DISPLAY;
    DWORD file_type = -1;

    /* this makes it easier to add flags */
#define FIND_ARG(op)                                                        \
    if (!lstrcmpiA(argv[i], "cc") || !lstrcmpiA(argv[i], "cxx")             \
        || !lstrcmpiA(argv[i], "cpp")) {                                    \
        comment_mode op CC_COMMENT_DISPLAY;                                 \
    } else if (!lstrcmpiA(argv[i], "c")) {                                  \
        comment_mode op C_COMMENT_DISPLAY;                                  \
    } else if (!lstrcmpiA(argv[i], "asm")) {                                \
        comment_mode op ASM_COMMENT_DISPLAY;                                \
    } else if (!lstrcmpiA(argv[i], "c|c++")) {                              \
        comment_mode op C_AND_CC_COMMENT_DISPLAY;                           \
    } else if (!lstrcmpiA(argv[i], "auto")) {                               \
        comment_mode op AUTO_COMMENT_DISPLAY;                               \
    } else if(!lstrcmpiA(argv[i], "py")) {                                  \
        comment_mode op PYTHON_COMMENT_DISPLAY;                             \
    } else if(!lstrcmpiA(argv[i], "rs")) {                                  \
        comment_mode op (RUST_COMMENT_DISPLAY);                             \
    } else if (!lstrcmpiA(argv[i], "all")) {                                \
        comment_mode op ALL_COMMENT_DISPLAY;                                \
    } else {                                                                \
        error_messagea("Error: invalid arguments\n", help_message);         \
    }                                                                       \

    /* parse command line args */
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        if (!lstrcmpA(argv[i], "--line") || !lstrcmpA(argv[i], "-l")) {
            show_lines = true;
        }
        else if (i + 1 < argc && !lstrcmpA(argv[i], "-r")) {
            ++i;
            if (!lstrcmpiA(argv[i], "true")) {
                recursive_directory_search = true;
            }
            else if (!lstrcmpiA(argv[i], "false")) {
                recursive_directory_search = false;
            }
            else {
                error_messagea("Error: invalid arguments\n", help_message);
            }
        }
        else if (argv[i][0] == '-' && argv[i][1] == '-'
            && argv[i][2] == 'r' && argv[i][3] == 'e'
            && argv[i][4] == 'c' && argv[i][5] == 'u'
            && argv[i][6] == 'r' && argv[i][7] == 's'
            && argv[i][8] == 'i' && argv[i][9] == 'v'
            && argv[i][10] == 'e' && argv[i][11] == '=') {
            argv[i] += 12;
            if (!lstrcmpiA(argv[i], "true")) {
                recursive_directory_search = true;
            }
            else if (!lstrcmpiA(argv[i], "false")) {
                recursive_directory_search = false;
            }
            else {
                error_messagea("Error: invalid arguments\n", help_message);
            }
        }
        else if (!lstrcmpA(argv[i], "--no_line") || !lstrcmpA(argv[i], "-nl")) {
            show_lines = false;
        }
        else if (!lstrcmpA(argv[i], "--display_comment_count") || !lstrcmpA(argv[i], "-dcc")) {
            display_comment_count = true;
        }
        else if (!lstrcmpA(argv[i], "--hide_comment_count") || !lstrcmpA(argv[i], "-hcc")) {
            display_comment_count = false;
        }
        else if (argv[i][0] == '-' && argv[i][1] == '-'
            && argv[i][2] == 'm' && argv[i][3] == 'o'
            && argv[i][4] == 'd' && argv[i][5] == 'e'
            && argv[i][6] == '=') {
            argv[i] += 7;
            FIND_ARG(= );
        }
        else if (i + 1 < argc && !lstrcmpA(argv[i], "-m")) {
            ++i;
            FIND_ARG(= );
        }
        else if (argv[i][0] == '-' && argv[i][1] == '-'
            && argv[i][2] == 'm' && argv[i][3] == 'o'
            && argv[i][4] == 'd' && argv[i][5] == 'e'
            && argv[i][6] == '=') {
            argv[i] += 7;
            FIND_ARG(= );
        }
        else if (i + 1 < argc && !lstrcmpA(argv[i], "-e")) {
            ++i;
            FIND_ARG(|= );
        }
        else if (argv[i][0] == '-' && argv[i][1] == '-'
            && argv[i][2] == 'd' && argv[i][3] == 'i'
            && argv[i][4] == 's' && argv[i][5] == 'a'
            && argv[i][6] == 'b' && argv[i][7] == 'l'
            && argv[i][8] == 'e' && argv[i][9] == '=') {
            argv[i] += 10;
            FIND_ARG(&= ~);
        }
        else if (i + 1 < argc && !lstrcmpA(argv[i], "-d")) {
            ++i;
            FIND_ARG(&= ~);
        }
        else if (!lstrcmpiA(argv[i], "--help")) {
            WriteFile("stdout", stdout, help_message, lstrlenA(help_message), NULL, NULL);
        }
        else if (((file_type = GetFileAttributesA(argv[i])) & ~FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) && file_type != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES) {
            read_file_comments(argv[i], comment_mode, show_lines, display_comment_count);
        }
        else if (file_type != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES && (file_type & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) {
            if (recursive_directory_search) {
                read_comments_in_directory(argv[i], comment_mode, show_lines, display_comment_count);
            }
            else {
                read_comments_in_directory_non_recursive(argv[i], comment_mode, show_lines, display_comment_count);
            }
        }
        else {
            error_messagea("Error: invalid arguments\n", help_message);
        }
    }

    /* cleanup */
    LocalFree(argv - 1);

    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

`argva.c`

```
/* from https://stackoverflow.com/a/42048224 also how hard is it to provide an ansi version of CommandLineToArgW windows? */
/*************************************************************************
 * CommandLineToArgvA            [SHELL32.@]
 *
 * MODIFIED FROM https://www.winehq.org/ project
 * We must interpret the quotes in the command line to rebuild the argv
 * array correctly:
 * - arguments are separated by spaces or tabs
 * - quotes serve as optional argument delimiters
 *   '"a b"'   -> 'a b'
 * - escaped quotes must be converted back to '"'
 *   '\"'      -> '"'
 * - consecutive backslashes preceding a quote see their number halved with
 *   the remainder escaping the quote:
 *   2n   backslashes + quote -> n backslashes + quote as an argument delimiter
 *   2n+1 backslashes + quote -> n backslashes + literal quote
 * - backslashes that are not followed by a quote are copied literally:
 *   'a\b'     -> 'a\b'
 *   'a\\b'    -> 'a\\b'
 * - in quoted strings, consecutive quotes see their number divided by three
 *   with the remainder modulo 3 deciding whether to close the string or not.
 *   Note that the opening quote must be counted in the consecutive quotes,
 *   that's the (1+) below:
 *   (1+) 3n   quotes -> n quotes
 *   (1+) 3n+1 quotes -> n quotes plus closes the quoted string
 *   (1+) 3n+2 quotes -> n+1 quotes plus closes the quoted string
 * - in unquoted strings, the first quote opens the quoted string and the
 *   remaining consecutive quotes follow the above rule.
 */

LPSTR *WINAPI CommandLineToArgvA(LPSTR lpCmdline, int *numargs)
{
    DWORD argc;
    LPSTR *argv;
    LPSTR s;
    LPSTR d;
    LPSTR cmdline;
    int qcount, bcount;

    if (!numargs || *lpCmdline == 0)
    {
        SetLastError(ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER);
        return NULL;
    }

    /* --- First count the arguments */
    argc = 1;
    s = lpCmdline;
    /* The first argument, the executable path, follows special rules */
    if (*s == '"')
    {
        /* The executable path ends at the next quote, no matter what */
        s++;
        while (*s)
            if (*s++ == '"')
                break;
    }
    else
    {
        /* The executable path ends at the next space, no matter what */
        while (*s && *s != ' ' && *s != '\t')
            s++;
    }
    /* skip to the first argument, if any */
    while (*s == ' ' || *s == '\t')
        s++;
    if (*s)
        argc++;

    /* Analyze the remaining arguments */
    qcount = bcount = 0;
    while (*s)
    {
        if ((*s == ' ' || *s == '\t') && qcount == 0)
        {
            /* skip to the next argument and count it if any */
            while (*s == ' ' || *s == '\t')
                s++;
            if (*s)
                argc++;
            bcount = 0;
        }
        else if (*s == '\\')
        {
            /* '\', count them */
            bcount++;
            s++;
        }
        else if (*s == '"')
        {
            /* '"' */
            if ((bcount & 1) == 0)
                qcount++; /* unescaped '"' */
            s++;
            bcount = 0;
            /* consecutive quotes, see comment in copying code below */
            while (*s == '"')
            {
                qcount++;
                s++;
            }
            qcount = qcount % 3;
            if (qcount == 2)
                qcount = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            /* a regular character */
            bcount = 0;
            s++;
        }
    }

    /* Allocate in a single lump, the string array, and the strings that go
     * with it. This way the caller can make a single LocalFree() call to free
     * both, as per MSDN.
     */
    argv = LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, (argc + (size_t)1) * sizeof(LPSTR) + (strlen(lpCmdline) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    if (!argv)
        return NULL;
    cmdline = (LPSTR)(argv + argc + 1);
    lstrcpyA(cmdline, lpCmdline);

    /* --- Then split and copy the arguments */
    argv[0] = d = cmdline;
    argc = 1;
    /* The first argument, the executable path, follows special rules */
    if (*d == '"')
    {
        /* The executable path ends at the next quote, no matter what */
        s = d + 1;
        while (*s)
        {
            if (*s == '"')
            {
                s++;
                break;
            }
            *d++ = *s++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        /* The executable path ends at the next space, no matter what */
        while (*d && *d != ' ' && *d != '\t')
            d++;
        s = d;
        if (*s)
            s++;
    }
    /* close the executable path */
    *d++ = 0;
    /* skip to the first argument and initialize it if any */
    while (*s == ' ' || *s == '\t')
        s++;
    if (!*s)
    {
        /* There are no parameters so we are all done */
        argv[argc] = NULL;
        *numargs = argc;
        return argv;
    }

    /* Split and copy the remaining arguments */
    argv[argc++] = d;
    qcount = bcount = 0;
    while (*s)
    {
        if ((*s == ' ' || *s == '\t') && qcount == 0)
        {
            /* close the argument */
            *d++ = 0;
            bcount = 0;

            /* skip to the next one and initialize it if any */
            do {
                s++;
            } while (*s == ' ' || *s == '\t');
            if (*s)
                argv[argc++] = d;
        }
        else if (*s == '\\')
        {
            *d++ = *s++;
            bcount++;
        }
        else if (*s == '"')
        {
            if ((bcount & 1) == 0)
            {
                /* Preceded by an even number of '\', this is half that
                 * number of '\', plus a quote which we erase.
                 */
                d -= bcount / 2;
                qcount++;
            }
            else
            {
                /* Preceded by an odd number of '\', this is half that
                 * number of '\' followed by a '"'
                 */
                d = d - bcount / 2 - 1;
                *d++ = '"';
            }
            s++;
            bcount = 0;
            /* Now count the number of consecutive quotes. Note that qcount
             * already takes into account the opening quote if any, as well as
             * the quote that lead us here.
             */
            while (*s == '"')
            {
                if (++qcount == 3)
                {
                    *d++ = '"';
                    qcount = 0;
                }
                s++;
            }
            if (qcount == 2)
                qcount = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            /* a regular character */
            *d++ = *s++;
            bcount = 0;
        }
    }
    *d = '\0';
    argv[argc] = NULL;
    *numargs = argc;

    return argv;
}
```

to build use

```
@echo off
cl.exe -nologo -Oi -O2 -GS- comments.c -link -subsystem:console -nodefaultlib kernel32.lib shell32.lib
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use the standard library

> This all started when I wanted to make a simple program [...]

Your program is much more complicated than necessary because you are not using the standard library. While it may be an interesting challenge to see how to write a program without using the standard library, [you already did that](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/248175/simple-windows-implementation-of-the-cat-command). Now it just is not a productive use of your time. It makes the program much longer than necessary, which means the chances of there being bugs in your code is also higher than necessary. Also, your program is not portable to other operating systems.

So, to improve your program: rewrite it so it is portable C code that uses the standard library.